# Can solving inequalities result in output in this format?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Reduce[{1 + x + a x^2 > 0, x > 0}, x, Reals]
```

get the result:

```
(a < 0 && 0 < x < 1/2 Sqrt[(1 - 4 a)/a^2] - 1/(2 a)) || (a >= 0 && 
   x > 0)
```

Can we obtain this form:

```
(a < 0 && 0 < x < (-Sqrt[1 - 4 a] - 1)/(2 a)) || (a >= 0 && x > 0)
```

and solve this:

```
Reduce[{1 + x + a x^2 < 0, x > 0}, x]
```

get the result:

```
a < 0 && x > 1/2 Sqrt[(1 - 4 a)/a^2] - 1/(2 a)
```

Can get this form:

```
a < 0 && x > (-Sqrt[1 - 4 a] - 1)/(2 a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform to the simpler form using FullSimplify:

```
FullSimplify[1/2 Sqrt[(1 - 4 a)/a^2] - 1/(2 a), Assumptions -> a > 0]

-((1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a])/(2 a))
```

which returns your desired form. If you want to start with your original expression:

```
ans = Reduce[{1 + x + a x^2 > 0, x > 0}, x, Reals]
FullSimplify[ans[[1, 2, 5]], Assumptions -> a > 0]
```